# How to print information at certain index in array from main method?

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I haven't coded in over a year and I'm really struggling to remember anything. I have 100 tabs open trying to relearn but I'm truly stuck.

This is my main method.

```java
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StudentDatabase database = new StudentDatabase();
        database.addStudent("Joe Schmo", 1101, 3.2);
        database.addStudent("Katie Katerson", 31415926, 3.7);
        database.addStudent("Watson TheBassetHound", 12345, 2.4);
        database.printDatabase();
        
        StudentDatabaseLL databaseLL = new StudentDatabaseLL();
        databaseLL.addStudent("Joe Schmo", 1101, 3.2);
        databaseLL.addStudent("Katie Katerson", 31415926, 3.7);
        databaseLL.addStudent("Watson TheBassetHound", 12345, 2.4);
        databaseLL.printDatabase();
    }
}
```

In another code file I need to print all the information of a student at a certain index. I literally cannot figure it out.

```java
public class StudentDatabase {
    private Student[] database;

    public StudentDatabase() {
        database = new Student[0];
    }

    public void addStudent(String name, int idNumber, double gpa) {
        Student student = new Student(name, idNumber, gpa);
        Student[] newDatabase = new Student[database.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
            newDatabase[i] = database[i];
        }
        newDatabase[newDatabase.length - 1] = student;
        database = newDatabase;
    }

    public void printDatabase() {
        for (int i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
            Student student = database[i];
            System.out.println(student.getName() + ": (ID=" + student.getIdNumber() + "), (gpa=" + student.getGPA() + ")");
            System.out.println();
        }  
    }

public class findStudentbyIndex {
    
    public void findStudentbyIndex(String[] args){
        int[] intArray = StudentDatabase              
                )
    }
}
```

This is all I have. Could someone just point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you should write the function and you should declare this func in the StudentDatabase class, as it is a function of it (according to OOP)

```
public void findStudentbyIndex(int i)
{
  Student std = database[i];
  System.out.println(std.getName() + ": (ID=" + std.getIdNumber() + "), (gpa=" + std.getGpa() + ")");
}
```

Sorry for the edit, i'm kinda new to this...

Comment: I would add a check on `i` to make sure `i >= 0` and `i < database.length` so it doesn't crash when trying to access an index position that doesn't exist in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems a little bit complex for the expected result. You should not have such class like findStudentbyIndex.. the method should be part of StudentDatabase.

**Case 1: I will propose a solution using your implementation**
You should remove then your class findStudentbyIndex. Put everything in student database.

```
public class StudentDatabase {
    private Student[] database;

    public StudentDatabase() {
        database = new Student[0];
    }

    public void addStudent(String name, int idNumber, double gpa) {
        Student student = new Student(idNumber, name, gpa);
        Student[] newDatabase = new Student[database.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
            newDatabase[i] = database[i];
        }
        newDatabase[newDatabase.length - 1] = student;
        database = newDatabase;
    }

    public void printDatabase() {
        for (int i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
            Student student = database[i];
            System.out.println(student.getName() + ": (ID=" + student.getIdNumber() + "), (gpa=" + student.getGpa() + ")");
        }
    }

    public void getStudentById(int idNumber) {
        for (int i = 0; i < database.length;  i++) {
            if(database[i].getIdNumber() == idNumber) {
                System.out.println(database[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    // other version:
    public void getStudentById2(int idNumber) {
        for (Student student: database) {
            if(student.getIdNumber() == idNumber) {
                System.out.println(student);
            }
        }
    }

    // modern way
    public void getStudentById3(int idNumber) {
        System.out.println(
                Arrays.stream(database)
                        .filter(student -> student.getIdNumber() == idNumber)
                        .findFirst().get()
        );
    }
}
```

Here is how you'd call it in your main :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StudentDatabase database = new StudentDatabase();
    database.addStudent("Joe Schmo", 1101, 3.2);
    database.addStudent("Katie Katerson", 31415926, 3.7);
    database.addStudent("Watson TheBassetHound", 12345, 2.4);
    database.printDatabase();

    database.getStudentById(31415926);
    database.getStudentById2(31415926);
    database.getStudentById3(31415926);
}
```

**Case 2: why don't you use java features ? You have lists, Maps...**
In your code you have StudentDatabase and StudentDatabaseLL objects ... I do suppose they look the same.
Here is what I would do for your case:

```
public class Main {
    private static Map<String, List<Student>> studentListsMap = new HashMap<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> students;

        students = new ArrayList<>();
        students.add(new Student(11, "name1", 3.2));
        students.add(new Student(12, "name2", 4.335));
        students.add(new Student(13, "name3", 12.1));
        // will print all students
        printDatabase(students);
        System.out.println("*******");
        getStudentById(students, 11);

        studentListsMap.put("students", students);

        students = new ArrayList<>();
        students.add(new Student(11, "name1", 3.2));
        students.add(new Student(12, "name2", 4.335));
        students.add(new Student(13, "name3", 12.1));
        // will print all students
        printDatabase(students);
        System.out.println("*******");
        getStudentById(students, 12);
        getStudentById(students, 15);

        studentListsMap.put("studentsLL", students);
        
        // now you can also manage your two lists in the map
        System.out.println("from the map");
        printDatabase(studentListsMap.get("studentsLL"));
        System.out.println("*******");
        getStudentById(studentListsMap.get("studentsLL"), 13);
    }

    private static void printDatabase(List<Student> students) {
        for (Student student: students) {
            // here you'll use the toString from the Student POJO
            System.out.println(student);
        }
    }

    public static void getStudentById(List<Student> students, int idNumber) {
        System.out.println(
                students.stream().filter(student -> student.getIdNumber() == idNumber)
                        .findFirst().orElse(new Student(0, "John Doe", 0.0)));
    }

    public static void getStudentByIdV0(List<Student> students, int idNumber) {
        for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
            if (students.get(i).getIdNumber() == idNumber)
                System.out.println(students.get(i));

        }
    }
}
```

getStudentById is looking in your list of student if it founds the right student with the id you passed. If no result is found, it create a John Doe Student... It will print a student in all case

getStudentByIdV0, is checking student by idNumber and print it if found.

this code may look a little bit more complex but you do not have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Note: I supposed you were looking for idNumber... if not, just get by index and print result. Try to run the code in debug mode to see how the different objects are managed in your application. it's hard at the beginning to understand data structures. Good luck!